# contextual filter for a block view with relationship

Tags: blocks, views

I defined two content types : *Book*, *Quote*. A quote has a *Book* field, an entity reference to the book it is extracted from.

I want to build a block view to be displayed on each *Book* node page : all the quotes extracted from that book. In other words, all the quotes whose *Book* field value matches the NID of the current *Book* node.

So I defined

• a relationship `field_book : Content` (`Content using field_property_book`) ;

• a contextual filter : `(field_book : Content) Content : Book` set

- to use `Relationship` = `field_book : Content`
- `When the filter value is NOT available` :
  `Provide a default value` = `Content ID from the URL`
  (I also tried `Raw value from URL` + element number 2 : node/NID)

The view block displays no results. Obviously, I missed something about configuring a contextual filter for a block view ! Any ideas ? Help to a newbie with relationship greatly appreciated :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the contextual filter should NOT use the relationship, as the *Book* field is in the *Quote* content type!

Finally, this worked: contextual filter `(field_book : Content) Content : Book` set

• `Relationship` = `Do not use any relationship`

• `When the filter value is NOT available` : `Provide a default value` = `Content ID from the URL`